# TreeView/HierarchicalDataTemplate - How to get the selected item?

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

```
<TreeView 
     x:Name="TreeView"
     DataContext="{Binding ApplicationMenu, Mode=TwoWay}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationMenuNodes}"
     Width="Auto" 
     FontFamily="Segoe UI"
     BorderThickness="0" 
     BorderBrush="Transparent" 
     Background="Transparent" 
     >
     <TreeView.Resources>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate
             DataType="{x:Type businessobject:ApplicationMenu}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationMenuNodes}"
             />
     </TreeView.Resources>
 </TreeView>
```

I have a treeview with a hierarchical data template. This is bound to a collec tion of ApplicationMenu objects, each containing it's own collection of ApplicationMenu objects.

I'm trying to obtain the selected ApplicationMenu, but I can't seem to find an way to do so. I don't care if it's MVVM or code behind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about accessing the SelectedItem property of the TreeView and cast it to your type?: var item = TreeView.SelectedItem as ApplicationMenu;

Comment: Contrary to my last comment, `TreeView.SelectedItem` is readonly and can't be bound. Code-behind only. You can handle the `SelectedItemChanged` event of the treeview and update the viewmodel from there, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried using the SelectedItemChanged event, but it doesn't fire.